# Editing Database row via view causes nulls only for 2/3 values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

Simple enough, my system allows a logged-in user to then add more details, however when they enter the FullName, PostCode and MobileNumber only the last MobileNumber is stored into the database. The other 2 values are showing Null regardless of what I enter. I can also see on the view that the MobileNumber has gone through successfully, but nothing for the other 2. I realize also that using hiddenfor isn't safe and is only there for quick testing.

Here is my code minimized for readability;

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Premium([Bind(Include = "Id,FullName,PostCode,Email,EmailConfirmed,PasswordHash,SecurityStamp,PhoneNumber,PhoneNumberConfirmed,TwoFactorEnabled,LockoutEndDateUtc,LockoutEnabled,AccessFailedCount,UserName,SignUpDate")] ApplicationUser applicationUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(applicationUser).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("../Club/Payment");
    }
    return View(applicationUser);
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmailConfirmed)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PasswordHash)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SecurityStamp)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PhoneNumberConfirmed)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TwoFactorEnabled)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LockoutEndDateUtc)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LockoutEnabled)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AccessFailedCount)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SignUpDate)

    <p>Full Name</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <p>Mobile Number</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
    <p>Postcode</p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


    <div class="TextBox" style="margin-left:10px;padding-bottom:15px;"><input style="border-radius:6px;" class="RegisterButton" type="submit" value="Continue to payment"></div>
}
```

Attributes
[Picture of break line for applicationuser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Elm6.png)

In image you can see PhoneNumber goes through fine but FullName and PostCode are showing Null

Comment: When you drop a breakpoint on the first line of your POST method, do those properties have values?

Comment: The MobileNumber does but the other 2 don't. Give me a moment and I'll share the screenshot @devlincarnate

Comment: @devlincarnate Added

Comment: Are values being entered client side - if not that might be the cause of your NULLS. What is your controller code.

Comment: @PeterSmith the 3 values that I'm trying to enter are entered via client-side but only 1 of them is sent through?! The controller code is shown above, under "Controller"

Comment: Look at F12 Network tab and inspect the POST payload, to see the properties and values being sent to the Controller.

Comment: Had a look @devlincarnate and it's showing the PostCode, PhoneNumber and FullName all being sent through

Comment: Then try removing the named property binding on the controller method, just for testing, to see if the values then come through to the controller.

Comment: @devlincarnate removed it and no change. I can't work out at all why it sending only the mobile number. I'd expect either everything or nothing

Comment: Couldn't manage to fix it, so I got around it by sending the data through and setting it as fullname, number and postcode in the controller. Thanks for trying though guys